# Is there any way to massively increase the speed of searching through files when using Ubuntu's search function?

Tags: 16.04, ssd, search

I'm using an SSD with multiple partitions. If it requires dedicating a lot of computer resources to have this be faster, that's ok

I want to search the names of files, folders, and applications using the default search tool that appears when you press the ubuntu logo in the corner or press Super

Comment: Very little info here. What tool do you want to use for searching? What do you want to search? File names? File contents? An index based search will be much faster.

Comment: @vanadium I updated my question

Comment: You might take a look at the `Searchmonkey` application. It searches quickly/easily.